# My stateful widget does not update it's state when setState is called

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget, flutter-state, flutter-build, flutter-future

### Background

Inside the state object of my stateful widget, I have the following code.

```
class _PendingJobsState extends State<PendingJobs> {
  List<String> pendingJobs = [];      <------------------- I am trying to change the state of this variable.

  void updateListWithResponseData(List jobs) {
    BackendApi.call(
        endpoint: APIEndPoints.GET_PENDING_JOBS,
        data: {"email": GlobalData.userEmail},
        onSuccess: (data) {
          setState(() {           <---------------- I call set State here
            jobs = data['job_list'];
            print(pendingJobs);        <------------ State is not changed
            print(jobs);
          });
        },
        onFailed: (error) {
          print('Failed to fetch data!');
        });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    updateListWithResponseData(pendingJobs);    <------- This is where the function in which I call the setState is executed.
    super.initState();
  }
```

### Details about the above code

`List<String> pendingJobs = [];` is the variable that I am expecting to have a state change done.

The function defined right below the above variable called `updateListWithResponseData` takes a parameter of type `List`. It is also responsible for calling another utility function called `BackendApi.call()`.

I am calling the `udateListWithResponseData()` inside the `initState` and for the parameter of type `List` it takes, I am giving the `pendingJobs` variable that I have defined. (Since I am calling `setState` from within the `updateListWithResponseData()` function, I am expecting the the state of `pendingJobs` to change when `updateListWithResponseData` is called.)

**However, the state change I am expecting in the above point is not taking place.**

`BackendApi.call` is responsible for fetching data from a given url and it takes two callback functions for `onSuccess` and `onFailure` which are responsible for performing necessary actions depending on the data fetching is a success or not.

**An important note**

Removing the `List jobs` parameter from the `updateListWithResponseData` and directly referring to the `pendingJobs` variable is ***not*** a solution for me since I am expecting to extract the function called `updateListWithResponseData` to a separate dart file and call it from different widgets. **So I have to have that `List jobs` parameter in the function.**

---

I tried to debug this issue for some time now and could not find a solution. It would be really helpful if someone can point out why the state of `pendingJobs` is not changing and how to actually make it change. (Thanks.)

---

**Edit**

Since a lot of comments below seem to revolve around the `BackendApi.call()` function and since I had not included the code for that function in my original post I have edited this post to include the code for that.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:field_app/globalData/global_data.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'api_endpoints.dart';

typedef ValueChanged<T> = void Function(T value);

class BackendApi {
  static void call(
      {String endpoint,
      Map<String, dynamic> data,
      ValueChanged<Map<String, dynamic>> onSuccess,
      ValueChanged<String> onFailed}) async {
    try {
      var response = await http.post(APIEndPoints.API_ROOT + endpoint,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + GlobalData.authToken,
          },
          body: jsonEncode(data));

      Map<String, dynamic> apiResponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
      if (apiResponse != null) {
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          if (onFailed != null) {
            onSuccess(apiResponse);
          }
        } else {
          print(apiResponse['message']);
          print('code: ' + response.statusCode.toString());
          if (onFailed != null) {
            onFailed(apiResponse['message']);
          }
        }
      } else {
        print('Invalid API response format');
        print('code: ' + response.statusCode.toString());
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Failed to connect with backend API");
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry, but is `BackendApi.call` is using http request or using some sort of Future?

Comment: @Yeasin Sheikh yes it does. `Backend.call` is an async function that sends a `post http request`

Comment: can you try making `updateListWithResponseData()` async and using await.

Comment: In `setState` you should change the value of `pendingJobs`, not `jobs`. Btw a `FutureBuilder` is a better solution for this, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69286169/elements-from-webservice-doesnt-appear-in-drag-and-drop-list-in-flutter/69287718#69287718).

Comment: @YeasinSheikh there is a little problem with doing that because `BackendApi.call()` has a return type of `void`. So I can not `await` it even if I make the `updateListWithResponseData()` an async function.

Comment: Since `initState` can't be `async`, it would not make a difference anyway.

Comment: @PeterKoltai I checked your answer. But there are two problems, 1) I will be extracting that function `updateListWithResponseData()` to a separate dart class later to import that function into a few other widgets and use it there. `To do that I have to pass the 'jobs' as an argument.`. 2) I would like to use `FutureBuilder` for this too, but the code I am working on is written by someone else and they want to keep it with using `callbacks` when something is done, instead of using the `FutureBuilder`

Comment: Let me share and test it on your side and yes it will reflect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this behaviour is that dart parameters are passed by value. (i.e. a copy of the variable is passed with the variable data)

So here you are passing a copy of the values in `pendingJobs` which happens to be a reference to the list.

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    updateListWithResponseData(pendingJobs);    <------- This is where the function in which I call the setState is executed.
    super.initState();
  }
```

and now `updateListWithResponseData` has its own variable `jobs` that holds a copy of `pendingJobs` reference

```
Future<void> updateListWithResponseData(List jobs) async{
   await BackendApi.call(
        endpoint: APIEndPoints.GET_PENDING_JOBS,
        data: {"email": GlobalData.userEmail},
        onSuccess: (data) {
          setState(() {           <---------------- I call set State here
            pendingJobs = data['job_list'];
            print(pendingJobs);        <------------ State is not changed
            print(jobs);
          });
        },
        onFailed: (error) {
          print('Failed to fetch data!');
        });
  }
```

so what this `jobs = data['job_list'];` does is assaigning the local variable (to `updateListWithResponseData`) `jobs` value, this change will not be reflected on `pendingJobs` as you are only updating the copy within `updateListWithResponseData`.

to fix this you remove the assignment `jobs = data['job_list'];` and replace it with  `jobs.addAll(data['job_list']);` this way `pendingJobs` value will get updated too.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer worked for me. There is one thing I would like to clarify from your answer. In your answer you mentioned `to fix this you remove the assignment jobs = data['job_list']; and replace it with  jobs.addAll(data['job_list']); this way pendingJobs value will get updated too.`. Now since `updateListWithResponseData`  has it's own variable called `jobs`, how come `jobs.addAll(data['job_list']);` update the actual `pendingJobs` variable we wanted instead of updating the local variable that was scoped to the function?

Comment: I think I figured the answer to the above comment I have typed. `jobs = data['job_list']` changes the reference to `data[job_list]` from `pendingJobs`. However when we are doing the `jobs.addAll[data['job_list']]` we do not use the `assignment operator`. Hence the reference to the `pendingJobs` is not changed and it makes changes on the `pendingJobs`

Comment: That is correct. That is exactly what happens, and that is the expected behaviour of "Pass by value" as the called function receives a copy of the value (in your case a reference to a list) and stores it as a local variable, and when you assign any value to that variable you lose the passed value from the caller thus losing the possiblity to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```dart
Future<void> updateListWithResponseData(List jobs) async{
   await BackendApi.call(
        endpoint: APIEndPoints.GET_PENDING_JOBS,
        data: {"email": GlobalData.userEmail},
        onSuccess: (data) {
          setState(() {           <---------------- I call set State here
            pendingJobs = data['job_list'];
            print(pendingJobs);        <------------ State is not changed
            print(jobs);
          });
        },
        onFailed: (error) {
          print('Failed to fetch data!');
        });
  }
```

And on `initState`:

```
updateListWithResponseData(pendingJobs);
```

Here is a demo widget of that workflow

```dart
class ApplicantsX extends StatefulWidget {
  const ApplicantsX({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ApplicantsX> createState() => _ApplicantsXState();
}

class _ApplicantsXState extends State<ApplicantsX> {
  int a = 0;
  Future<void> up(int v) async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      setState(() {
        a = v;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    up(234);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: Text("$a"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank your for the answer and your effort. I ran this code and still did not update the change, Also as soon as I put the term `await `, my editor gives me a warning saying `await applied to void which is not a future`

Comment: Yes. It is still there after the `Futue<void>`. I think that it is because `BackendApi.call()` does not return a `Future`. So awaiting it gives a warning I think....

Comment: Can you include `BackendApi.call` and I think it should return `Future<void>` instead of void because we're requesting on HTTP and its response will be future?

Comment: I tried this. But still the state does not change.... I think that making the `BackendApi.call`, `Future<void>` is not necessary, because that api util is written in a way that rather than returning any data, we just provide a callback function to it to act upon that data. I will edit my question to include the code for `BackendApi.call`

Comment: can you try with `static Future<void> call() async {}`

Comment: `jobs = data['job_list'];` - shouldn't it be `pendingJobs = `?

Comment: yes it will be ,,

Answer (score 0):

First thing: if you want to do an asynchronous task which will change state when resumed on first build, always do that in a WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback.
Second thing: you don't have to use state variable as parameter for state method.

Try this:

```
class _PendingJobsState extends State<PendingJobs> {
  List<String> pendingJobs = [];      <------------------- I am trying to change the state of this variable.

  void updateListWithResponseData() {
    BackendApi.call(
        endpoint: APIEndPoints.GET_PENDING_JOBS,
        data: {"email": GlobalData.userEmail},
        onSuccess: (data) {
          setState(() {           <---------------- I call set State here
            pendingJobs = data['job_list'];
            print(pendingJobs);
          });
        },
        onFailed: (error) {
          print('Failed to fetch data!');
        });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => updateListWithResponseData()) <------- This is where the function in which I call the setState is executed.
  }
```